# Django. Get currently used object inside the template

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django. Currently I'm writing a webpage for a friend's dog kennel. I have a base.html with a list of dogs. By clicking on any of them you go to their profile(which takes a child template profile.html) which exists on their own respective URL according to the name of the dog.

My problem is that I can't refer to the dog object *inside* the template. I need to take out the dog's name, its description and image.

Here are my files:

models.py

```
class dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dogs', blank=False, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    dog_list = dog.objects.all()
    template = 'base_extend.html'
    return render(request, template, {'dogs' : dog_list})

def dog_view(request, name):    
    dog_list = dog.objects.all()
    dog_view = get_object_or_404(dog, name=name)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', locals())
```

base.html

```
{% for dog in dogs %}
<a href="{% url 'profile' dog.name %}">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="{{ dog.main_image.url }}" height=400px width=400px alt="">
    <h2 align=center>{{ dog.name }} 
    {% if dog.gender == 'ML' %}
        &#9794; 
    {% else %} 
        &#9792;
    {% endif %}</h2>
    <p>{{ dog.description }}</p>
</div></a>
```

And in profile.html I need the following:

```
<img src="{{ dog.main_image.url }}">
    <h2>{{ dog.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ dog.description }}</p>
```

How do I refer to the object of the dog, for which the current URL was created? Variable {{ name }} returns only the string, and {{ dog_list }} returns the list of all dogs created.

{{ dog_list.1 }} (or any other number) almost does what I need, except I don't know how to get the number of the current dog.

Thank you for reading such a long question to the end. I hope for your answer, since I googled all over the internet and couldn't find the answer (or perhaps I made wrong requests). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to populate a dictionary object like you do in your `home` view rather than calling locals(). **Explicit is better than implicit.**

```
def dog_view(request, name):
    dog_list = dog.objects.all()
    dog_view = get_object_or_404(dog, name=name)

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'dogs': dog_list,
                                            'dog': dog_view}
```

To explain the actual problem though, you're referencing `dog.attribute` in your template, but by calling `locals()` it's passing `dog_view` as the object reference. If you stick with locals (which I wouldn't recommend) you'd need to reference `dog_view.attribute` in your template.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the difference between locals() and a populated dictionary, so I hadn't even thought the problem could be there. 
From now on I'll stick to dictionaries. Thank you very much.

Comment: Locals IS a dictionary. So is globals.

Comment: Sure, it's a dictionary, but it's not explicit – which is what led to his issue in the first place. I modified the answer to remove the word "actual".

Comment: well, the dictionary vs locals is a matter of preference.  both end up the same.  the main sticking point is that a missing context attribute name won't throw a KeyError within the template when you used `dog` instead of `dog_view`..  It would have done so on either locals() or the explicit dictionary **within Python code**.  A Django template however is built to be tolerant to missing references and it just ignores them.  More robust to the end user, but it puts the onus on you to be careful.  I don't agree/disagree with Tyler, but either way is still open to goofs in template refs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the dog object you have in your view as a context variable to your template and then you can access the dog's attributes such as name, description, etc. by doing (in this case) `dog_view.name`, `dog_view.description`, `dog_view.main_image.url`. If you print out `locals()` you'll see that this is a dict of your local variables + values and args. So, inside this dict you have `"dog_view": <Dog object>, ...` so you're actually already passing the dog instance.

But, as you see in the other answer you would preferably pass these explicitly to your template I wouldn't recommend using `locals()`.